# How to save the position of an element to a json file and display the element based on that json file using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, drag-and-drop

The div elements are Drag & Drop.

I would like to save the position of `div class="prod_image_wrap">` into a json file.

Than I would need to display those elements based on that Json using the coordinates in the same page or it could be a different one using html and Javascript.

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  // Retrieve positions from JSON file or initialize with default values
  var savedPositions = {
    // Initialize with default positions (you can change these values)
    "https://via.placeholder.com/130": {
      "left": "0px",
      "top": "0px"
    }
  };

  // Function to save positions to JSON file (via AJAX)
  function savePositionsToJSON() {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(savedPositions);
    // Here, you should use AJAX to send jsonData to the server and save it to a JSON file.
    // Replace "your-server-endpoint" with the URL where your server-side script will handle the saving.
    // $.post("your-server-endpoint", { data: jsonData }, function(response) {
    //   console.log("Positions saved to JSON.");
    // });
  }

  // Function to update positions object and save
  function updatePositionAndSave(id, position) {
    savedPositions[id] = position;
    savePositionsToJSON();
  }

  // Make .prod_image_wrap elements draggable
  $(".prod_image_wrap").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var imageId = $this.find("img").attr("src"); // Get the image source as an ID

    // Initialize position based on savedPositions or default (if not found in savedPositions)
    var position = savedPositions[imageId] || {
      "left": $this.css("left"),
      "top": $this.css("top")
    };

    // Apply initial position
    $this.css({
      "left": position.left,
      "top": position.top,
      "position": "absolute"
    });

    // Make elements draggable
    $this.draggable({
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        updatePositionAndSave(imageId, ui.position); // Save the new position on drag stop
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.prod_image {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prod_image_wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 265px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.dim_error {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.prod_image_top {
  display: block;
}

.prod_image img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  max-width: 110px;
}

.prod_image img.bag_img {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.prod_name {
  max-width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imagecount {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Outfit Builder</h1>

<div class="prod_image_wrap">
  <div class="prod_image">
    <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130" alt="Product 1" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_name">Product 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="prod_image_wrap">
  <div class="prod_image">
    <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130" alt="Product 2" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_name">Product 2
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you missing? Saving using AJAX as suggested in your code or save in localStorage using `JSON.stringify(savedPositions)` ?

Comment: @mplungjan i need to be able to share the url and the positions of the elements would stay. so i think localStorage won't work in my case. No Idea how to deal with Ajax.

Comment: I have an endpoint something like : example.com/saved_values.json

Comment: You will need to save to a server or create a URL to share or both

Comment: @mplungjan  How am I saving it to a server ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some version of how to read the values from URL (?search) from hash (#hash) and from file

```
  // Initialize with default values
  let savedPositions = {
    "https://via.placeholder.com/130": {
      "left": "0px",
      "top": "0px"
    }
  };
  const url = new URL(document.location.href)
  const sp = url.searchParams;
  //const posParam = sp.get("posparam")
  posParam = URL.hash?.slice(1) ?? "";
  console.log(posParam);
  // force testdata
  const encodedJSONParms = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(
    {
    "https://via.placeholder.com/130": {
      "left": "110px",
      "top": "120px"
    }
  }
    ));
  // then Retrieve positions from URL or JSON file 
  if (!posParam) {
    //sp.set("posparam",)
    /// url.hash = encodedJSONParms
    console.log(url.toString());
    location.hash = encodedJSONParms
  }
  else {
    savedPositions = decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(posParams));
    console.log(savedPositions)
    move();  
  }
  else {
    fetch("https://example.com/saved_values.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(object => savePositions = object);
      move()
  }
```

and then have

```
function move() {
    $(".prod_image_wrap").each(function() { .... })
}
```

to save you can do a [fetch with POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data) to the server that then has to write the JSON file if it is ONE file to serve all users or a database